# Implement BouncingScrollPhysics animation in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

How can I implement something like *BouncingScrollPhysics* that is one of *ScrollPhysics* type in flutter's listView in react native.

I know there is `bounce` property for react native, but it only works for iOS, I need for android too.

So how can I active this prop for android too.

Here is What I want to implement in react native.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Try this module – [react-scrollbooster](https://github.com/oberonamsterdam/react-scrollbooster). It's a port of this js lib [scrollbooster](https://github.com/ilyashubin/scrollbooster), also see options here.

```
import { useScrollBoost } from "react-scrollbooster";

const Component = () => {
  const [viewport, scrollbooster] = useScrollBoost({
    direction: "vertical",
    friction: 0.2,
    scrollMode: "transform"
    // ...optional options
  });

  return (
    <div ref={viewport}>
      <div>
        <h2>Drag to scroll</h2>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("?");
          if (scrollbooster) {
            console.log(scrollbooster.getState());
          }
        }}
      >
        Click me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-swirles-b688o?file=/src/App.js)

[Demo](https://b688o.csb.app/)

Comment: I need for react native.